# meteorjs iron-router and empty link tags

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, iron-router

I am using iron-router in my meteorjs project.  I am using an after: handler to set a session variable which shows or hides a leaflet map.  I can't put the map in my templates like normal because meteorjs obliterates the map div and it's state.

Now I am adding bootstrap menus and dropdowns, which are built as anchor tags with href="#" like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
    <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
    <li class="disabled"><a href="#">Disabled</a></li>
</ul>
```

Clicking on these menus doesn't leave the url, but it causes iron-router to call my after: handler with each click or submenu drilldown.

Is there a way to prevent this?  It's not detrimental to my project but it seems unclean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default `iron-router` attaches to links with the selector `a[href]`. I found this didn't work so well (especially with bootstrap plug-ins) and developed a fix https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/pull/324

You can modify the link selector like so:

```
if (Meteor.isClient){
  IronLocation.configure({
    linkSelector: "a[href][data-iron]"
  });
}
```

With this setting, iron-router will only pick up on links that have the `data-iron` attribute.

The alternative is to try and bind to `a[href="#"]` and call `event.stopPropagation()` before it hits the `iron-router` link handler.

Comment: I can't figure out how to get your code to work.  IronLocation isn't available in the global namespace, and if you try this code inside  Meteor.startup() the configure() method is not available.  So HALP lol

Comment: Make sure that you're using `0.6.2` of `iron-router`. Also, if you read the `package.js` file- you can see that `IronLocation` is available only on the client. (will updated example to show).

Comment: I realized I was using an older version of iron-router.  I'm guessing i just need to call bindEvents somewhere

Answer (score 2):

You can prevent the default behavior when you click a # link.

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'appLayout'
  ...
});
```

If your layout is appLayout

```
Template.appLayout.events({
  "click [href=#]": function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```

Comment: This way also works great for me.  Both your answers helped a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Router intercepts all link clicks in order to work properly, so it's not an easy thing to do (nor a good idea, I guess) to prevent it.

You can solve the issue by placing your map normally in the template, but within [a constant block](http://docs.meteor.com/#constant). They are useful whenever you do some custom DOM manipulation.

Comment: awesome, thanks for the map info. I already have a constant block and it works great. I guess mentioning the map wasn't 100% relevant

Answer (score 1):

Just use [ian:bootstrap-3](https://github.com/ianmartorell/meteor-accounts-ui-bootstrap-3/)

this will work with iron-router per default

```
meteor add ian:bootstrap-3
```